# Unmarshal JSON depending on key

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am receiving JSON formatted data from the network, and I need to unmarshal it depending on a key.
Here is the data example:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "11883920": {
      "fieldA": 123,
      "fieldB": [
        {
          "fieldC": "a",
          "fieldD": 1173653.22
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "bar": {
     "123": {
       "fieldE": 123
     }
   }
  "anyOtherkey": {...}
}
```

The logic is that, if the key is `foo` it sould be unmarshaled as `fooStruct`, and if `bar` - as a `barStruct`.
What is the best way to implement this logic? (I don't want to unmarshal it to `map[string]interface{}`, maybe it is possible with `json.NewDecoder()` function but I could not get the expected result).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a type with both fields present:

```
type MyType struct {
    Foo      *fooStruct `json:"foo,omitempty"`
    Bar      *barStruct `json:"bar,omitempty"`
    OtherKey string     `json:"other_key"`
}
```

Unmarshal the JSON into that type, and simply check ig `Foo` and or `Bar` are nil to know what data you're working with.

Here's a playground [Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/j1ltL7JA0Ps) of what this would look like

The essence of it is:

```
type Foo struct {
    Field int `json:"field1"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Message string `json:"field2"`
}

type Payload struct {
    Foo   *Foo   `json:"foo,omitempty"`
    Bar   *Bar   `json:"bar,omitempty"`
    Other string `json:"another_field"`
}
```

The `Foo` and `Bar` fields are pointer types, because value fields would make it a bit more cumbersome to work out which field was actually set. The `omitempty` bit allows you to marshal the same type to recreate the original payload, as `nil` values will just not show up in the output.

To check which field was set in the original JSON string, simply write:

```
var data Payload
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
if data.Foo == nil && data.Bar == nil {
    // this is probably an error-case you need to handle
}
if data.Foo == nil {
    fmt.Println("Bar was set")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Foo was set")
}
```

Nothing more too it